# What is an example of a non-Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

A Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is a manifold equipped with a metric tensor ($g$) that is both symmetric and positive definite. Now if the metric tensor is symmetric but not positive definite, then it's a *pseudo-Riemannian* manifold. But what the case of a manifold equipped with a metric tensor $(M,g)$ such that $g$ is not symmetric(regardless of whether it is or is not positive definite)?

That is, $\forall (x,y) \ such \ that (\ x \neq  y \ )  \in T_{p}(M) \ g(x,y)\neq g(y,x)$ at any point p in M.

Comment: An example of a non-Riemannian manifold is a manifold without the **extra data** of a Riemannian metric. An example of a non-symmetric "metric" would be a symplectic form, like the standard symplectic form on $\Bbb R^{2n}$.

Comment: There is a type of metric (generalized Riemannian metric) so called _Finsler metric_. It is not reversible in most cases. Like metric represented by mounting up to the summit of a mountain and going down. i.e. $F(x,y)\neq F(y,x)$.

Comment: @s.harp that's pretty much the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @C.F.G This is certainly not a definition of Finsler metric I'm familiar with.

Comment: What do you intend to use your metric tensor for? If it is for defining "arclength", by the usual formula $\int \sqrt{g(\dot{\gamma}(t), \dot{\gamma}(t))} dt$, notice that you can replace a non-symmetric $g (x, y)$ with $\frac{1}{2} (g (x, y) + g (y, x))$ without changing the value of "arclength". So there is nothing gained from allowing non-symmetric metric tensors here, unlike when allowing non-definite metric tensors.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I didn't give any definition of Finsler metric and I don't know what definition you are talking about?

Comment: "That is, $∀(x,y)∈T_p(M) g(x,y)≠g(y,x)$ at any point $p∈M$." This can never be satisfied. Take $x= 0$ or $y=0$. I guess you mean something else.

Comment: A class of non-symmetric generalized Riemannian metrics is studied here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.05217.pdf

Comment: @PaulFrost I meant a metric that is not symmetric everywhere(except when x = 0 or y = 0). I should have made that clear in the OPost.

Comment: Your current definition implies that $g$ is not even a tensor. Do you really mean it?

Comment: According to John Lee, a topological manifold is a structure with following conditions: A Hausdorff space; Second countable; locally Euclidean of dimension n. A Riemannian manifold requires additional information about local inner product called metric tensor $g$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, a Finsler metric is not a tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first try to make sense of the question (in its current revised version; my guess is that this is not the last revision). Recall that a **metric tensor** by the very definition is required to be symmetric and positive definite. Hence, a "nonsymmetric metric tensor" is an oxymoron. My best guess is that OP really means not a metric tensor, but a **covariant 2-tensor** $g$ on a manifold $M$. The nonsymmetry condition, as stated in the revised version, says:

> For every $p\in M$ and every two distinct vectors $x, y$ in $T_pM$, we have $g(x,y)\ne g(y,x)$.

Note that if $\lambda\in {\mathbb R}$
is different from $1$ and $x\in T_pM$ is a nonzero vector, then (by the definition of a tensor!)
$$
g( \lambda x, x)= \lambda g(x, x)= g(x, \lambda x). 
$$
Hence, for $y=\lambda x$, we get $g(x,y)=g(y,x)$.  Thus, there are no tensors satisfying the required inequality.

OK, maybe OP really means that $x, y$ are linearly independent in the stated assumption (nonvanishing of $x, y$ is then automatic).
Then the nonsymmetry requirement becomes:
$$
g(x, y)\ne g(y, x)
$$
for every $p\in M$ and all linearly independent vectors $x, y\in T_p$. Then tensors with this property do exist in dimension 2. For instance, one can take the area form $\omega=dx_1\wedge dx_2$ on the plane $M$. Then for all $p\in M, x, y\in T_pM$ we have
$$
\omega(x,y)=-\omega(y,x)\ne \omega(y,x)
$$
as long as $x, y$ are linearly independent.

It is a nice linear algebra exercise to see that tensors satisfying **my** nonsymmetry condition do not exist on manifolds of dimension $\ge 3$. In particular, symplectic forms (on manifolds of dimension $\ge 4$) fail this nonsymmetry condition.